# Add dired buffers to evil jump list

Tags: evil, dired

I want dired buffers to be included in jump list so I can visit them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>. One possible catch is that My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> binding is taken by `ido-dired`. What I've tried so far (without success):

```
(evil-add-command-properties #'ido-dired :jump t)
(evil-add-command-properties #'dired-jump :jump t)
(evil-add-command-properties #'dired-noselect :jump t)
(evil-add-command-properties #'dired :jump t)
(evil-add-command-properties #'ido-file-internal :jump t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks on reddit pointed me to the right direction here: https://redd.it/8rg6zk

Will quote the response from [@whism](https://www.reddit.com/user/whism):

> Looks `like evil--jumps-push` requires that `(buffer-file-name)` returns something, or that `(buffer-name)` matches the regexp in `evil--jumps-buffer-targets` in order to proceed. It looks like dired buffers would fail here by default. Perhaps that is your issue?

It got me to the idea of changing dired buffer names to be prefixed with `Dired:` and adding this prefix to `evil--jumps-buffer-targets` regexp:

```
(defun my-rename-dired-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (string-match-p "Dired:" (buffer-name))
    (rename-buffer (concat "Dired:" (buffer-name)) t)))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-rename-dired-buffer)
(setq evil--jumps-buffer-targets "\\(\\*\\(\\new\\|scratch\\)\\*\\|Dired:.+\\)")
(evil-add-command-properties #'dired-find-file :jump t)
```

Comment: What happens if you create a dired buffer, find a file from the buffer, kill the dired buffer, then try to jump back?  Does it jump to the last available jump point, or does the jump fail with an error?

Comment: @purple_arrows Good question, just checked it out. Emacs will create a new buffer in fundamental mode with the name "Dired:buf_name" and will jump to it. It's not really an issue for me since I rarely kill buffers this way. But I can see how it could easily be fixed buffer deletion hook or something like this.

Comment: Found an issue with "this buffer already in use" when renaming a buffer to the name which already exists. Passing `t` as the second argument to the `rename-buffer` solves it, I've updated the answer